# Laravel Model is being converted Carbon Object Sometimes and Cannot use object of type Carbon\Carbon as array Error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, timezone, php-carbon

I'm doing some string operation for timezone conversion from legacy codebase.

I need to put `T` between date and time and I'm doing it using following logic.

```
$check_in= $model->checkin_date_time; // 2022-12-12 22:22:22
$check_in[10] = 'T'; // 2022-12-12T22:22:22
```

For some weird reason, I'm getting this error.

```
Cannot use object of type Carbon\Carbon as array
```

But it's not always. Error comes only 1-2 times per 2000 - 3000 request.

I'm using Carbon for the other places (or even in the other part of same function) but there isn't any cast for `$model`'s `checkin_date_time` property.

I'm not sure why `$model->checkin_date_time` was converted into Carbon Object.

Comment: Is `$model` the same Model every time? It should only be a `Carbon` instance if you have `protected $dates = ['checkin_date_time']` (or `protected $casts = ['checkin_date_time' => 'datetime']`, etc.) in your `Model.php`. Otherwise, it should be a `string`, and `$check_in[10] = 'T';` would work. You _can_ handle this  though; `if ($check_in instance of Carbon::class) { $check_in = $check_in->format('Y-m-d H:i:s); }`, then `$check_in[10] = 'T';`. Or, the reverse; `if (is_string($check_in)) { $check_in = Carbon::parse($check_in); }`, then `$check_in->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`$model->checkin_date_time` is not `"2022-12-12 22:22:22"` it's a Carbon (sub-class of DateTime) object. And when you try to convert it as a string (using `echo`, any kind of display or injecting it in another string, then it automatically format as `Y-m-d h:i:s`

If you want to output in another format use the `->format()` method instead:

```php
$check_in = $model->checkin_date_time->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s');
```

Anyway, it's really a bad idea to use the offset (`$check_in[10] =` syntax) to modify a letter in a string, those kind of micro-optimizations don't worth it.